# Where to download Xamarin Help Content?

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, help-viewer

I'm using Xamarin for Visual Studio 2015 and cannot find a link to download Help contents.

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin has extensive documentation available online.  AFAIK there is not way to download it all for offline reference, although many pages are available as PDF.